# how to get help options for data types in python

Tags: python

using below **for loop** to see all help options for dictionaries

`for me in dir(dict):
    if not me.startswith("__"):
         help(dict.me)`

> error is AttributeError: type object 'dict' has no attribute me

Once resolve it i can see all data types help options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pivoting from the only answer and your question:

```
for me in dir(dict):
    if not me.startswith('__'):
        help(getattr(dict, me))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for me in dir(dict):
    if not me.startswith('__'):
         help(me)
```

Comment: its printing all information for help(dict) and ending 
no Python documentation found for 'setdefault'
I wanted the information which has no dunder those values information only